# How to ask a question that has been asked before but not given a full answer

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I have a question about my Web Applications Stack Exchange post: [My Twitter account isn't showing up in other's notifications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/94993/my-twitter-account-isnt-showing-up-in-others-notifications)

Ten days ago I was searching Stack Exchange for solutions to a peculiar bug. I found someone else who had asked about the same problem, and had received a generic answer on the level of "do you know how Twitter works", all of which I already knew and none of which answered my question. The problem was that that question was locked. So I re-asked the question, in hopes of getting the answer that I actually needed, but had the thread dismissed because it was too similar to a previous question - even though the answer to that question had been incomplete! Is there some etiquette I'm missing here?

Comment: If it *is* the same question, once you get enough reputation, you can also offer bounties for this purpose.

Answer (score 7):

The usual accepted approach on all SE sites is to ask the question your way and include a link to the existing question that you feel doesn't give an acceptable answer.

State in your question why you find the other question fails to give you your answer.

It has to be said that you still run the risk of people voting to close your question as duplicate.  However, in most circumstances the question will be kept open.  The fact that you have done some homework and reviewed the earlier question will count in your favour.

As to whether this approach would work in the specific example that you mention - I couldn't say.  Editing "*Those answers didn't work*" into a closed question will usually not get a question reopened in my experience.